# println every element in collection and return TRUE

Tags: clojure

I'm doing it this way:

```
(coll? (map #(println (.toString %)) java-objects))
```

The function has to return `TRUE`, that's why this `coll?` predicate. I supposed there is a better, a more elegant way?

ps. And this function doesn't work, since it is "lazy". Can you recommend a right way to go through all elements in a collection and do something with each of them.

Comment: Prefer `clojure.core/str` to `.toString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the value of expression but only side effect then it's better to use `doseq` instead of `map`:

```
(do (doseq [o java-objects]
      (println (.toString o)))
    true)
```

`doseq` doc:

```
clojure.core/doseq
([seq-exprs & body])
Macro
  Repeatedly executes body (presumably for side-effects) with
  bindings and filtering as provided by "for".  Does not retain
  the head of the sequence. Returns nil.
```

Answer (score 2):

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doall

```
(doall (map #(println (.toString %)) java-objects))
```

It will return you

```
(nil nil nil ...)
```

If you need true:

```
(do
    (doall (map #(println (.toString %)) java-objects))
    true)
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer, but I would have used `dorun` instead of `doall`.